# Delay on animations after switching tab in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a plane animation, when a plane reach the city, it opens up the info about the city and changes the background of the site and so on, but when I click on another tab in the browser and then go back to my site the timing of those pop ups is messed up, is there anything how could I fix it? Here is my whole HTML code, just write me if you also need CSS for any reason, thank you and have a great day.
P.S. I also got bootstrap,css,jquery etc. linked up, but this site doesn't let me show it in the code bellow.

My site: http://pouze.kvalitne.cz/blog

My code:`

```
<!-- -----*-----NAVIGAČNÍ MENU-----*----- -->
<div class="menu-btn" id="burger">
    <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
</div>
<!-- Start Home Section -->
<div id="home">
    <div class="airplane"></div>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
        <img src="img/transparent.png">
    </div>
    <div class="london" id="london_point">
        <img src="img/point.png" width="40px" id="london_point">
    </div>
    <div class="london_info" id="london_info">
        <li>
            <div class="london_speech"></div>
            <h2>London</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl.
                <a href="#london">Read more...</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="washington">
        <img src="img/point.png" width="40px" id="washington_point">
    </div>
    <div class="washington_info" id="washington_info">
        <li>
            <div class="washington_speech"></div>
            <h2>Washington D.C.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl.
                <a href="#washington">Read more...</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="brasilia">
        <img src="img/point.png" width="40px" id="brasilia_point">
    </div>
    <div class="brasilia_info" id="brasilia_info">
        <li>
            <div class="brasilia_speech"></div>
            <h2>Brasília</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl.
                <a href="#brasilia">Read more...</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Home Section -->
<!-- Start About Us Section -->

    <div class="about-container">
        <div class="about-text">
            <p>About our BLOG</p>
            <p>...Half programming rest traveling</p>
            <p>We enjoy traveling, especially to very different places. ...</p>
            <p>
                Shipton's traveling companion, Penelope Something, hysterically filled in what little she knew to Jake Weller and Emile Corday, both of whom visited the patient at the hospital. ...
            </p>
            <button>See more</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_one"></div>
<!-- End About Us Section -->
<!-- Start Video Section -->
<div class="about-container_two">
    <div class="about-text_">
        <p>What is our purpose</p>
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <iframe width="889" height="369" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BtNAX36j1c4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <!-- <img src="../blog/img/unnamed.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />-->
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe width="889" height="369" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TYHh5PLcReY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe width="889" height="369" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EwmvBnR_xtA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Video Section -->
<!-- Start Copyright Section -->
<div class="card text-center" style="margin-top: 50%;">
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        &copy; Michal & Kuba
        <p>2020</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Copyright Section -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var washington_start = setTimeout(washington_timer, 10000);
    var london_stop;
    var washington_start;
    var washington_stop;
    var brasilia_start;
    var brasilia_stop;

    function washington_timer() {
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.transition = '.5s';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.zIndex = '4';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.scale = '1';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/washington.jpg')";
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
        washington_stop = setTimeout(washington_stoper, 3400);
    }

    function washington_stoper() {
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.zIndex = '2';
        document.getElementById("washington_info").style.scale = '0';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
        document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
        brasilia_start = setTimeout(brasilia_timer, 4250);
    }

    function brasilia_timer() {
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.transition = '.5s';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.zIndex = '4';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.scale = '1';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/brasilia.jpg')";
        document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
        brasilia_stop = setTimeout(brasilia_stoper, 6000);
    }

    function brasilia_stoper() {
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.zIndex = '2';
        document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.scale = '0';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
        document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
        london_start = setTimeout(london_timer, 10000);
    }

    function london_timer() {
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.transition = '.5s';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.zIndex = '4';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.scale = '1';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/london.jpg')";
        london_stop = setTimeout(london_stoper, 6000);
    }

    function london_stoper() {
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.zIndex = '2';
        document.getElementById("london_info").style.scale = '0';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
        document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
        washington_start = setTimeout(washington_timer, 10000);
    }
</script>
```

`

Comment: Generally speaking, browsers will de-prioritize timers, animations etc for pages that aren't visible. One option is to run the timer in a WebWorker as those run in a background thread and aren't affected as bad.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your advice, I'm trying to figure out how the WebWorker works, so I could try it on my site.